# How to add a vertex between two other vertices in Blender?

Tags: blender

I want to add a single vertex between two vertices in Blender (I am following the Blender Guru's donut tutorial)

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzIvj.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select your edge and hit space then type "subdivide" and select "subdivide"